# How to correctly get thread name in Java?

Tags: java, multithreading

I have this class for creating a thread in Java

```
package org.vdzundza.forms;

import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;

public class DrawThread extends Thread {
    private static final int THREAD_SLEEP = 500;
    public CustomShape shape;
    private Graphics g;

    public DrawThread(CustomShape shape, Graphics g) {
        this.shape = shape;
        this.g = g;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (true) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(THREAD_SLEEP);
                Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
                g2d.setColor(this.shape.getColor());
                g2d.fill(this.shape.getShape());
                System.out.println(String.format("execute thread: %s %s",
                        Thread.currentThread().getName(), this.getName()));
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The console displays the following text as an output

```
execute thread: red rectangle Thread-2
execute thread: yellow ellipse Thread-3
```

My code which creates the new thread:

```
customShapes[0] = new CustomShape(
new Rectangle2D.Float(10, 10, 50, 50), Color.RED,
    "red rectangle");
customShapes[1] = new CustomShape(new Ellipse2D.Float(70, 70, 50, 50),
Color.YELLOW, "yellow ellipse");
for (CustomShape cshape: customShapes) {
    Thread t = new Thread(new DrawThread(cshape, this.getGraphics()),
    cshape.getName());
    threads.add(t);
    t.start();
}
```

My Question is: Why does `Thread.currentThread().getName()` return the correct thread name whilst `this.getName()` returns another?

Answer (score 59, accepted):

> Why `Thread.currentThread().getName()` return correct thread name whilst `this.getName()` return other?

Your `DrawThread` class `extends Thread` but then you start it by calling:

```
new Thread(new DrawThread(...));
```

This is not correct.  It means that the actual thread that is created is *not* the same `Thread` from `DrawThread`.  `DrawThread` should be implementing `Runnable` and *not* extending thread.  It should be:

```
public class DrawThread implements Runnable {
```

Your code works because `Thread` is also a `Runnable`.  Because there are two thread objects, when you call `this.getName()` on the `DrawThread` object that is not the thread that is actually running so its name is not properly set.  Only the wrapping thread's name is set.  Inside of the `DrawThread` code, you should call `Thread.currentThread().getName()` to get the true name of the running thread.

Lastly, your class should probably be `DrawRunnable` if it `implements Runnable`.  :-)

Answer (score 8):

You are passing an instance of your `DrawThread` to a `Thread(Runnable)` constructor. It doesn't care that your class extends `Thread`; it only cares that it `implements Runnable`.

The thread that gets started is the one created by `new Thread(...)`—and you didn't set the name on that one.

In general, extending `Thread` is bad practice and should always be avoided. You are already almost there because you don't `start` the instance of your class, but pass it to a separate `Thread` instance.

Answer (score 3):

There are two Objects involved, the DrawThread object that contains the run method, and the new Thread created using it as the Runnable.

this.getName obtains the name of the unstarted DrawThread. The current thread is the one you started.

Answer (score 2):

**simple call:**

```
new DrawThread().start();
```

to start new Thread

```
DrawThread drawThread;              // declare object of class DrawThread 
drawThread = new DrawThread();      // instantiate object of class DrawThread
drawThread.start();                 // call start to start DrawThread
```

(DrawThread is extending Thread class) so involves:

```
  public synchronized void start() {
        checkNotStarted();

        hasBeenStarted = true;

        nativeCreate(this, stackSize, daemon);   // here Thread is created 
  }
```

u call is ike **PUT THREAD INSIDE THREAD** (AS RUNNABLE) by calling:

```
public Thread(Runnable runnable) {
    create(null, runnable, null, 0);
}
```