# It it hard to figure it out myself that how current thread works in this code worked

Tags: java, multithreading

```
class MyThread extends Thread{ //
    public void run(){
        Thread t1=Thread.currentThread();
        System.out.println(t1.getName());
    }
 }
 class Demo{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        Thread t1=new MyThread();
        t1.setName("MyThread");
        t1.run();
        t1.start();
    }
 }
```

It prints "main" when it calls run().Why it is not the "MyThread"

Comment: Because `run()` is just a method call, it is still running in the context of the main thread.  The thread itself doesn't become a new thread until you call `start()` which happens after the call to `run()`.

Comment: But then I swap the method calling statements, the output remains same and  start()  prints "main". How?

Comment: Because `run()` is still just a method call.  And it still happens in the context of the calling thread.  It's *main* that calls `run()`, not some other thread.  The same thing happens with any other method call: they're always called with the context of the caller's thread.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14187383/how-to-correctly-get-thread-name-in-java

Answer (score 2):

It is not the `MyThread` class because `run()` method is just call, it is still running in the context of the main thread.

A thread itself does not turn into a new thread until call to `start()` which happens after the call to `run()`.